# What is the function of "doch" here?

Tags: meaning

> Betrachtet sie **doch einfach** als notwendiges Übel.
>
> [compared to] : Betrachtet sie **einfach** als notwendiges Übel.

I wonder if it serves to put an emphasis on the adverb "einfach", perhaps in a similar manner as « tout » in «  tout simplement » in French?

Incidentally, I assume it is not correct to say:

> [incorrect?] : Betrachtet sie **doch** als notwendiges Übel.

Comment: Just a particle word to tone the meaning of a sentence. German is rather full of them; English not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its like "just" here.

Another sentence.

"Denk einmal darüber nach!" -> "Think about it!".
"Denk doch einmal darüber nach!" -> "Just think about it!".

It's more aggressiv in the most cases.

Comment: I thought that doch in imperative cases would soften the sentence. Denk mal! vs Denk doch mal! oder Wart mal! vs Wart doch mal!

Answer (score 0):

» Betrachtet sie doch einfach als notwendiges Übel. «

» Betrachtet sie einfach als notwendiges Übel. «

» Betrachtet sie doch als notwendiges Übel. «

All three are correct.

It's not an emphasis. *Doch* in this case implies that the people you're talking to are considering the object in question as something other than a necessary evil (perhaps a major nuisance or an apocalyptic catastrophe)

Now you jump onto the scene with the quote above and persuasively steer them to not make such a fuss and just accept it as a necessary evil.

It's one of those little words without a meaning but with functions, in this case to soften up the injunction so it becomes an invitation to adopt an alternative view. Like a smoothness factor.

*Doch einfach* occurs frequently. Why don't you just take the easy road? Fahr doch einfach andersrum. Geh doch einfach zu Fuß. Mach es doch einfach nochmal. Geh doch einfach nach Hause. Mach doch einfach weiter. Hör doch einfach auf. Kauf doch einfach ein neues Gerät. (Das alte ist kaputt.) Sieh's doch einfach positiv.

Comment: Hi. So does "einfach" too serve to soften up the injunction?